# Android PixelCopy. Is that possible to take screenshot of another app with PixelCopy?

Tags: android-pixel-copy

PixelCopy require as first argument Window or Surface. I can get it for my app, but can't get window from service for another apps. I was even trying to get it with AccessibilityNodeInfo and AccessibilityWindowInfo - I can get all windows sizes on the screen and names of their packages, but can't cast AccessibilityWindowInfo to Window so can't pass this to PixelCopy. I am doing it with Kotlin but answer with Java also would be helpful.